# Fix a cascading css menu to the top

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get a menu to stick to the top of the page no matter where you scroll, but I am unable to do so. Here is my code:

```css
body#beta a#beta,
body#zte a#zte,
body#honor a#honor,
body#samsung a#samsung,
body#market a#market,
body#beta a#beta,
active {
    background-color: #0D47A1;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
active {
    background-color: #0D47A1;
}
.active li {
    background: #fff;
}
ul a,.dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-width: 120px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: #000;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Progam 1</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
             <ul class="active" id=menu position=fixed>
             <li><a href=""  style="color:black;  " id=home>Home Page</a></li>
             <li><a href=""  style="color:black; " id=zte>ZTE</a></li>
             <li><a href=""  style="color:black; " id=honor>Honor</a></li>
             <li><a href=""  style="color:black; " id=samsung>Samsung</a></li>
             <li><a href="" style="color:black; " id=market>Newsletter</a></li>
        </div>
    </ul>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Progam 2 BETA</a></li>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <ul class="active" id=menu position=fixed>
                <li><a href=""      style="color:black;  " id=beta> Progam 2 Home Page</a></li>

        </div>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I've tried doing

```
position:fixed;
```

and

```
top:0px;
```

but it will only become a jumbled mess.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get the entire menu to be fixed at the top?

Comment: Please setup a fiddle or something so we can properly advise

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. Will look into jfiddle

Edit: here is the jfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/foue4tx7/

Comment: your html structure is completely messed up you should work on that first

Comment: You have unecessary html here... ul then another ul. Anyway, when you set the wrapping ul as fixed, it will not affect the rest of the elements so you just have to push your content down.

Comment: You have too many ul elements, and the elements aren't properly nested (you open a div before a ul, then close it before closing the ul).The id's and position attributes on your ul elements aren't enclosed in quotes. You have two ul elements sharing the same id. You need to read up on your html first.

Comment: A UL must be open before a div?  And okay, i'll close the elements in quotes.



Sorry if the code is crappy, this is my first time making a website.

Comment: As others have pointed out, you have issues with your **html**. A `<ul>` can only have `<li>` as child elements. You have `<a>` and `<div>` as child elements of a `<ul>`. You are also setting `position: fixed;` improperly on your elements. `position` is not an element attribute, set it in a _style_ attribute, i.e. `style="position: fixed;"`. Not only that, it looks like you're using Bootstrap. Bootstrap [supports fixed navigation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top) (you need additional markup to implement).

Comment: If you open any element before another, the second must be closed before the first. This is called nesting. e.g. `<div><ul><li></li></ul></div>` is valid, in your code you do this `<div><ul><li></li></div></ul>` which is not valid.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help. I will study up on parent and child elements and redo this code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
position:fixed;
top:0;
```

is all you need.

This gets the element outside the normal flow of content and places it at the *top of the **viewport*** no matter where you scroll in the content (*by default the viewport is the browser window - but it can be a parent `iframe` or any parent element that has a few select 3d transforms*).
You have to make sure the `body` element doesn't have any margins (`body{margin:0;}` will take care of that).

Your problem is that you do not have a normal flow of content (at least in this example).

Another rather important thing to add is that IoS devices ignore `position:fixed;` and replace it with `position:absolute;`. <strike>Apparently, they consider `position:fixed;` a liability to online security (citation needed)</strike>. It's a bad design decision, but it's how things are. Anyway, in order for your element to remain "fixed" on IoS, you need to make sure it doesn't have a parent with a set position (other than `static`), which kind of beats the whole purpose of using `position:fixed` in the first place.
Yeah, I know. Talk to the apple.

Note: in some newer versions of IoS, the `position:fixed;` property is only ignored in special states, such as when the keyboard is opened.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the security flaw. 

So by setting the body margin to 0, it allows the menu to flow over it? (best way for me to ask)

Comment: You will want to set a `padding-top: <some value>` on the body. If you don't the first bit of content you have will be hidden behind the navigation bar.

Comment: Not unless the navigation bar is toggle-able, @hungerstar. Anyway, that's what getting an element outside the flow of content means. It will overlap the normal flow of content. It's normal and expected behavior.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I realize that. It was a comment/tip for the OP who is new to the game and might not fully comprehend that and how to account for it. Cheers.

Comment: Correct, am new to the game and is hopelessly lost (java and SQL is my thing, web dev aint) Thanks both of yall

Comment: i haven't heard that `position:fixed` is a security flaw. i thought it was just considered bad UX on mobile since "fixed" elements appear to move as the user pans around the page.

Comment: @worc - Being a bad UX experience does not justify ignoring web standards. It's just a very bad decision and a huge mistake on their part. I should be able to place a fixed element that scrolls with the content once the user scrolls down but comes back in view when the user scrolls up a bit. Apple denies me that and I have to write a lot of unnecessary `js` or `ts` to achieve it cross browser. "Bad decision" is me being polite.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu no disagreement here, Apple will ignore standards to meet some internal UX standard that they want. but that's not the same as considering it a "security liability."

Comment: It's clearly not a security liability. Not more than browsing the web in itself. I read it somewhere (can't find it now - haven't bookmarked it) and found the idea of invoking security as a reason for such a bad decision mind-blowingly hilarious.